# 404 on Safari but fine in Chrome when using an image

Tags: image, safari, cloud, http-status-code-404

When I use an image of an iPad from my cloud server on my cloud site (same location) it works fine in Chrome

But in **Safari the image 404's**

If I navigate to the image URL in Safari I get this

[image]

Chrome is fine on the same path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this looks to be a problem raised by cloudflare, and the fix was to add ?format=webp to the image.

not the best fix in my opinion, but looking to a wider fix but keeping the cloudflare setting the same